# For what value of k onwards is it pointless for a computer to compute the probability mass function of the Poisson distribution

Tags: computational-mathematics, poisson-distribution

I am asking my computer to compute the probability mass function of  $X \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda)$, a Poisson random variable. The function is:

$$\Pr(X =  k) = \frac{{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k }}{k!}$$

I know that for some value of $k$, the probability $\Pr(X =  k)$ will be negligibly small, say, smaller than $1 \times 10^{-16}$. Is there a function of $\lambda$ that approximates what this value of $k$ should be?

Comment: Use Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly define one.  Let $IP(\lambda, p)$ be the smallest $k$ such that $\frac {e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!} \lt p$.  It will do funny things when $\lambda$ is large because no bin may have much content or when $p$ is not small, but will do what you expect in the range of interest.

To compute it, you can use Stirling's approximation on the factorial to say $\frac {e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}\approx \frac {e^{-\lambda}(e\lambda)^k}{k^k\sqrt{2 \pi k}}$  This can't be solved for $k$ analytically (except using the W function) but it is easy to solve numerically.  For $p=1E-16$ I find $$\begin {array} {c|c} \lambda&k\\ \hline 0.01&6.404739\\0.1&9.702412\\1&17.81112\\2&22.66661\\3&26.52406\\4&29.88898\\5&32.94789\\10&45.87589\\20&66.85164\\30&85.16933\\40&102.1354\\50&118.2484\\\end {array}$$  For small $\lambda$ the $\lambda^k$ term will do most of the work bringing down $p$, for moderate $\lambda$ it will be the $k!$ and for large $\lambda$ it will be the $e^{-\lambda}$

Comment: @Alex:  I found a bug in the spreadsheet, now fixed.  The values have changed.

Comment: and for computing this estimated $k$, looking at the $\log$ can be helpful, for avoiding the precision problem we are trying to avoid :)

Comment: What are the advantages to solving the approximate equation numerically, compared to solving the original equation numerically?

Comment: @Alex:  it is defined on the reals since we got rid of the factorial.  Most root finders assume the ability to evaluate the function at any real number.  You could also have that advantage by changing the $k!$ to $\Gamma(k+1)$ in the denominator.  Not a big advantage.